# Generate .trx file without timestamp

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, vstest

Before the following command generates `my-test.trx` but by updating our server it generates `my-test_2019-04-14_09-59-39-114.trx`. And this is not mentioned in its document (https://aka.ms/vstest-report)

`dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=my-test.trx"`

Now such this step in Jenkins cannot find the file with timestamp.

`step([$class: 'MSTestPublisher', testResultsFile:"$TEST_PATH/TestResults/my-test.trx", failOnError: true, keepLongStdio: true])`

Server's update list:

```
dotnet-runtime-deps-2.1:amd64 2.1.10-1
dotnet-host:amd64 2.2.4-1
dotnet-hostfxr-2.1:amd64 2.1.10-1
dotnet-runtime-2.1:amd64 2.1.10-1
aspnetcore-runtime-2.1:amd64 2.1.10-1
dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2:amd64 2.2.4-1
dotnet-hostfxr-2.2:amd64 2.2.4-1
dotnet-runtime-2.2:amd64 2.2.4-1
aspnetcore-runtime-2.2:amd64 2.2.4-1
dotnet-sdk-2.1:amd64 2.1.603-1
dotnet-sdk-2.2:amd64 2.2.203-1
```

Any idea how to stop adding this timestamp or fixing Jenkins code?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the Jenkins pipeline this in way:

```
script {
    TRX_FILE = sh (script: "ls $TEST_PATH/TestResults/my-test*.trx", returnStdout: true).trim()
}
echo "TRX_FILE : ${TRX_FILE}"
step([$class: 'MSTestPublisher', testResultsFile:"$TRX_FILE", failOnError: true, keepLongStdio: true])
```

Comment: This was a great start for what I had to do. Thanks.